# Java Installer - help needed

Tags: java, installation

First of all hello and thanks for taking the time to help me with my problem.

I need to develop an application in Java which will use SQLite. The application needs to be cross platform (starting from Windows XP onwards, Linux and MAC).

I need to select an installer (be it free or paid) which will check whether JRE is installed on the target machine and if it isn't to install it, to install and create the DB and install the application.

If you have experience with any installer please recommend it and tell me what the pros and cons of it are. I need to compile a list and need to present it to my project manager so he can take appropriate actions.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Many people have recommended IzPack. It is not an option because it already requires JVM in order to run.

Comment: you want to create an application in Java. So the person who will install your application will definitely need JVM to run your application. Hence `IzPack` is perfect for you.

Comment: Not sure why you got 3 down votes - I found a list of Java installers here: http://java-source.net/open-source/installer-generators hope it helps. As far as I can see there is only JSmooth for Windows that checks for an Installed JVM, you may need to provide multiple installers for the different platforms.

Comment: @PC As he rightly pointed out, he wants the installer to start up and check if a JVM is installed and take appropriate action if no JVM is present.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, most of packaging solutions has an option to pack the JRE inside the installer. So, the executable, be it an exe, bin or rpm will be shipped with proper JRE inside. This is better approach as it minimizes the number of of unexpected issues you can run into if you assume that the JRE would be available on target system e.g: permissions, JRE install location, JRE version etc.

The executable will unpack the JRE it was shipped with and launch java application (your installer).

There are many multi-platform packaging solutions both free/open source and commercial.

The most popular commercial is [InstallAnywhere](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installanywhere.htm) by Flexera. It comes with handy IDE, XML-based bean configuration (think of bean as a single step or screen during UI-based installation process) and many custom checks you might wish to perform during the installation. You can create a silent installation with response file to ship your installation on many boxes inside an enterprise. You also have the ability to create custom beans for your installation that will perform custom logic.

[Install4J](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html) is also commercial solution  - I have not tried it because it does not support all platforms I needed.

Another commercial install wizard is [JExpress](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installanywhere.htm) by Denova. It is also fully customizable and has the same platform support coverage as InstallAnywhere, it comes with the full suite of features but the development of the custom installation is less handy and it has less integration with Windows OS (for the time I played with it I could not perform a registry check and based on the result do actionA or action B).

Open source packaging wizards I tried are [lzpack](http://izpack.org/) it is good and flexible but the lack of good documentation affects the time you get the things done.

[InstallJammer](http://www.installjammer.com/) is another open source but it does not support all platforms - only basic windows and linux platform but I think that this project has been discontinued.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

> I need to select an installer (be it free or paid) which will check whether JRE is installed on the target machine and if it isn't to install it, to install and create the DB and install the application.

I suggest a two part strategy.

1. Check whether a suitable JRE is installed, and guide the user through upgrading if not.  Surprisingly, this is best done using a **JavaScript** supplied/maintained by Oracle themselves.  It is the [deployJava.js](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html).  If you an accept that the tool to ensure a JRE is present is not part of the installer itself, that opens up the field of potential installers considerably, but I *have a favorite.*
2. Install the rich client app. itself using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  `<disclaimer>`JWS is just so great that I have to repeat the blurb I wrote on that info. page`</disclaimer>`.

> Java Web Start (JWS) is the **Oracle** Corporation technology used to launch **rich client** (Swing, AWT, SWT) desktop applications directly from a network or internet link. It offers 'one click' installation for platforms that support Java.
>
> JWS provides many appealing features including, but not limited to, splash screens, desktop integration, file associations, automatic update (including lazy downloads and programmatic control of updates), partitioning of natives & other resource downloads by platform, architecture or Java version, configuration of run-time environment (minimum J2SE version, run-time options, RAM etc.), easy management of common resources using extensions..

Answer (score 0):

Well I have found this guide on how to create an [OS X installer](http://www.centerkey.com/mac/java/)
For Windows it seems that [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/) does what you want.

Also you may want to have a close look at [BitRock Installer](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com).

Comment: isn't this a bad practice? Using different installers for different platforms or is it perfectly okay?

Comment: It isn't pretty - but if you don't find any other option, what choice do you have?