# Bundle installation of java desktop app with SQLite (or any DB for example's sake)

Tags: java, swing, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Installer - help needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796658/java-installer-help-needed)

Hi and thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

I intend to use Launch4J or SmoothJ as installers for my desktop app developed in Swing. However along with the app I need to install a DB locally at the client. My question would be, how to bundle the installation of the app along with the installation of DB at the client?

Thanks

Comment: That's a bit harsh.. since I never got a concise answer. Plus, the first question dealt with which installer to use. Now I have a question regarding how to bundle the db with the app.

Comment: isn't that basic property of [Embedded database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database)

Comment: *"I never got a concise answer."* Perhaps the problem is expecting a concise answer about something for which a book could be written?  As it is, there is nothing distinguishing your two questions that would make me change the answer I gave on the other one, beyond saying 'Don't bundle the DB inside anything but its own installer.  Call that installer from the JNLP'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SQLite, there *is* no installation of the DB. The data is stored in a file, and your application makes calls to the SQLite API which access that file.

From http://www.sqlite.org/zeroconf.html:

> SQLite does not need to be "installed" before it is used. There is no "setup" procedure. There is no server process that needs to be started, stopped, or configured. There is no need for an administrator to create a new database instance or assign access permissions to users. SQLite uses no configuration files. Nothing needs to be done to tell the system that SQLite is running. No actions are required to recover after a system crash or power failure. There is nothing to troubleshoot.
>
> SQLite just works.

Comment: right basic property of Embedded database